# PHP start date and current date both are same but so its showing me date is Past

Tags: php

I am comparing two dates with current date, but problem occur only when start date and current date both are same. I have logic if start date and current date both are same so output is `Ongoing` but it's showing me `past`.

following are my code

```
$endDate = new DateTime($row['end_date']);
$startDate = new DateTime($row['start_date']);
$current_date = new DateTime();
if ($startDate < $current_date){
    if($endDate < $current_date){
        $row["status"] = "Past";
    }else if ($endDate == $current_date){
        $row["status"] = "Ongoing";
    }else{
        $row["status"] = "Ongoing";
    }
}else if ($startDate > $current_date){
    $row["status"] = "Upcoming";
}else if ($startDate == $current_date){
    $row["status"] = "Ongoing";
}else{
    $row["status"] = "Ongoing";
}
```

example with actual value:

```
start date = "27-02-2023"
end date = "27-02-2023"
current date = "27-02-2023"
```

its shwoing me "past" instead of "ongoing"

Comment: Are you taking into account the "time" portion? That is, if you assign a new DateTime to "now" (27/2/23 17:49 for me) won't that always be later than a DateTime created from just a date because it'll assume the time is 00:00? 00:00 is earlier than 17:49, so it's in the past. You need to compare just the date parts.

Comment: Update the question with examples of your actual values. Use `var_dump` to get values.

Comment: questin is updated with actual value @user3783243

Comment: `$current_date` IS NOT just a date it will look like `2023-02-27 17:58:44.191572` See [DEMO](https://3v4l.org/R6siO)

Comment: can you please suggest me whats change in my code for getting perfect result? @RiggsFolly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44693421/453348

Comment: You are doing `$current_date->format('d-m-Y')` somewhere? You shouldn't use integer comparisons on strings. I would convert these to epoch.

Comment: what should i change? actually i am new in php @user3783243

Comment: can you add answer? @RiggsFolly

Comment: [DEMO](https://3v4l.org/O5oeN#v8.2.3) Remember the time makes a difference. Use that demo code as a test bed for your code